# Realtime chart using flot jquery

Tags: jquery, plot, charts

I'm looking for a way to display a VM current CPU usage using a Flot (Jquery) Chart.

From now, i can draw simple lines but no clue on how to get the graphic move to the left as new data comes in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var d1 = [ [0,0] ];
         options = {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickDecimals: 0,
                    tickSize: 1
                },
                grid: {
                    backgroundColor: {
                        colors: ["#fff", "#eee"]
                    }
                }
        };

        function init() {                                              
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), d1, options);
        } /* init Function */

        function update(){
            for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
                d1.push([i, Math.floor(Math.random()*11)]);
            }
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1 ], options);
        }
        init();
        $("input.dataUpdate").click(function () {
            update();
        });         
    </script>
```

Any idea or maybe another plugin that can do the trick ?

edit :

I need to translate the associative array :

```
 [ [1, (random1)], [2, (random2), [3, (random2) ]
```

to

```
 [ [2, (random2)], [3, (random3), [4, (random4) ] (new element 4)
```

Don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was looking at their API and they have a 'setData' function that looks like it allows you to update an existing charts data.

http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt

[Update]
After looking at the above example in other browsers, the refresh rate when reconstructing the plot from scratch is a bit slow. I noticed undesirable flashes in between updates. Here is a better solution:

```
var xVal = 0;
var data = [[],[]];
var plot = $.plot( $("#chart4"), data);

function getData(){
    // This could be an ajax call back.
    var yVal1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    var yVal2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    var datum1 = [xVal, yVal1];
    var datum2 = [xVal, yVal2];
    data[0].push(datum1);
    data[1].push(datum2);
    if(data[0].length>10){
        // only allow ten points
        data[0] = data[0].splice(1);
        data[1] = data[1].splice(1);
    }
    xVal++;
    plot.setData(data);
    plot.setupGrid();
    plot.draw();
}

setInterval(getData, 1000);
```

I also put together a blog post about flot describing this in a bit more detail:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2011/01/web-charts-using-jquery-flot/

Bob

Comment: How to call this function ? plot.setData doesn't work ... sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Here is a flot example that is doing updating via ajax and settimer: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html

Comment: Yes, almost, but the plot doesn't slide here .. for a CPU monitoring it may become very unreadable with thousands of data.

Comment: Okay. I fiddle around a bit. Here is an example that is updating the axis: http://jsfiddle.net/y9brY/2/

Comment: Still some work to do. At some point you will probably want to throw away the oldest points. Also the horizontal labeling leaves little to be desired. But I think the original problem is solved.

Comment: Here is another update that keeps a max number (10 in this case) most recent points. http://jsfiddle.net/y9brY/3/

Comment: @Disco. Check out the update above. This code has a bit better performance than my original attempt.

Comment: @rcravens: your examples are becoming very helpful for me. Thanks a lot. Can you please share source code for the above given link(people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html).
Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shift` method on the array to remove the first element (i.e. shifting it to the left and decreasing its size by 1 element) and `push` to add to the end and increasing its size to its original size before the `shift` e.g.

```
d1.shift();
d1.push(new_element);
```

then display the plot again with $.plot(....)

Comment: Almost works except that new data I add like d1.push ([arraySize, randomValue]) never gets scrolled.

Comment: Hi, I've never used FLOT; I thought about it a couple of years ago, but it was a bit heavyweight for what I wanted. "shift()" will remove the first element and "push()" will add a new last element, which is what scrolling is all about so I don't understand why the FLOT graph doesn't scroll. How can it display the old first element when it no longer exists in the array?