# Plotting realtime bar chart after pre-populating data with flot.js

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruvj7/45/).

What I am trying to accomplish:

I want to poll the server for data, then populate the entire bar graph. After which I want to update the bar graph in realtime (or say every 1 minute).

This [site](http://bitcoinwisdom.com/markets/btce/btcusd) uses a graph (at the bottom) very much like what I'm trying to do.
As you can see, the initial data gets plotted, and then the graph updates, but I am stuck on how to update the ticks at the bottom, so the original data slides out to the left.

I am using the method suggested here: [Realtime chart using flot jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758602/realtime-chart-using-flot-jquery#answer-4759033)

I've tried using this, but doesn't do the trick:

```
yaxis: { 
        ticks: [1,2,3] 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `plot_bot.getOptions().xaxes[0].min`

Here is a [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UMt7d/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Completely missed getOptions()